# invert colormap in mlab

Tags: python, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I simply want to know how to invert a colormap in mlab.  I know in matplotlib you can simply add _r to the name of the colormap to invert the color scheme.  However it appears to be slightly different in mlab.  Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Couldn't you just `::-1` the map?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific.  For example could you write this out in simple line of code.

Comment: http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/api/mappers.html#chaco.api.ColorMapper.reverse_colormap  I don't use `mlab`, but I suspect that the function at that link will do the trick.

Comment: I would also be careful about invert vs reverse terminology.  Invert could also mean `(r, g, b) -> float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to **reverse** a colormap. Here is what works for me (it might not be the easiest solution, i am not an expert on mayavi), modified from [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_custom_colormap.html#example-custom-colormap)

```
s=mlab.surf(xx,yy,zz,colormap='GnBu')
lut = s.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut.table.to_array()
ilut = lut[::-1]
# putting LUT back in the surface object
s.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut.table = ilut
# forcing to update the figure once we have changed the LUT
mlab.draw()
mlab.view()
```

Answer (score 12):

Using the script recording of the mayavi pipeline, I found :

```
s.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.reverse_lut = True
```